# Why is my dictionary inside a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

I am importing from an sqlite3 file into a dictionary to insert into mongodb, I sort of have it working but the dictionary is nested in a list and I don't understand why or how to get it out.

```
    # python3.5

    import os
    import sqlite3 as lite
    from collections import defaultdict
    import pprint

    def dict_factory(cursor, row):
        d = {}
        for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
            d[col[0]] = row[idx]
        return d

    def open_sql(sql_folder, sql_name, sql_table):
        path_name = os.path.join(sql_folder,sql_name).strip()
        con = lite.connect(path_name)
        con.row_factory = dict_factory
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + sql_table) 
        contents = defaultdict(list)
        contents = cur.fetchall()
        pprint.pprint(contents)
        con.close()
        return contents
```

my output

```
[{'block_size': 512, 'img_offset': 0, 'obj_id': 2, 'vs_type': 1}]
```

what I want my output to be

```
{'block_size': 512, 'img_offset': 0, 'obj_id': 2, 'vs_type': 1}
```

Comment: Please cut this down to only the relevant code. I can't even tell where the prints are coming from. At the very least remove commented code.

Comment: `contents = defaultdict(list)` does nothing because you are re-assigning that variable the next line

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using `fetchall()`, use `fetchone()` instead:

```
contents = cur.fetchone()
pprint.pprint(contents)
```

Comment: I used fetchall() because I want all the content not just the first row. So are you saying I have to loop it? Yea... the document does say fetchall() returns a list.

Comment: @JenniferJohnson yeah, loop over the dictionaries in the list. Thanks.